# how to play the video in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I need to play the video in Xcode using objective-c. I have dragged an mp4 file in Xcode. And used the code:

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoname" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];

[self.avPlayer play];
```

But showing the error as nil in filepath.

Comment: While drag and drop to XCode did you check **check box copy item if needed ?**

Comment: i checked and given copy item ,i got the output ,thanks

Comment: Happy to listen, Welcome

Answer (score 0):

While adding item by drag and drop You should take Care following things

1) While drag and drop to **XCode**  you must check check box **copy item if needed**

2) Check Target on right panel should be checked with your current target

Answer (score 0):

try as

```
  NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoname" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviplayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:     streamURL];
  [moviplayer prepareToPlay];
  [moviplayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
  [self.view addSubview: moviplayer.view];
  moviplayer.fullscreen = YES;
  moviplayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
  moviplayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
  moviplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [moviplayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag  and drop video file into your project and must check box
   copy item if needed
2. Also add your video file  in build phases copy bundle Resources

[image]